# phpmyadmin error closing bracket was expected. (near ")"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I was trying to import a sql database in phpmyadmin, 
I'm getting error:
**A closing bracket was expected. (near ")" at position 194)**

Sql Query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wll_product` ( `product_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `product_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL, `product_type` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT )
```

I'm new to mysql, please help me out, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a comment after the COMMENT keyword (or leave COMMENT out). You will also need to make product_id key if you want to use auto_increment on it.

```
 CREATE TABLE `wll_product` (
`product_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`product_type` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'a comment',
KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Edit: as scaisEdge mentioned, only key is enough, not pk as I said before.

Comment: Thanks It worked Just had to add a `;` at the end. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have some error  the tinyint is numeric but you assigned a string '0' 
have comment pending  and missing key (mandatory on autoincrement)

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wll_product` ( 
  `product_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
  `product_type` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  key(product_id)
 );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE 'data' (
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  'title' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  'text' text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO 'data' ('id', 'title', 'text') VALUES(1, 'Hello World!', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla 
sapien eros, lacinia eu, consectetur vel, dignissim et, massa. Praesent suscipit nunc vitae neque. Duis a ipsum. Nunc a erat. Praesent 
nec libero. Phasellus lobortis, velit sed pharetra imperdiet, justo ipsum facilisis arcu, in eleifend elit nulla sit amet tellus. 
Pellentesque molestie dui lacinia nulla. Sed vitae arcu at nisl sodales ultricies. Etiam mi ligula, consequat eget, elementum sed, 
vulputate in, augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;');
```